# Problems after installing Monero GUI Wallet v0.18.0.0 for 64 bit Linux and using Ledger Nano S

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I cannot get my Ledger Nano S to work with the new Monero GUI Wallet v0.18.0.0 for 64 bit Linux.

My details are as follows:

1. I am using Linux MINT 20.1 Cinnamon
2. I have been using my Ledger Nano S with v0.17.3.1 GUI for approx. 2 years and have had no problems
3. I am also running a full node, and update the blockchain daily
4. Since I run the daemon as a full node (in order to help out the community), it is already running before I start the Monero GUI

In preparation for the Aug 13, I have downloaded, from "Get Monero" the latest GUI, v0.18.0.0.

When I start the daemon manually (via the terminal) it runs & updates my node's DB with no problems.

Also in preparation for Aug 13, I used Ledger's Live Manager and installed the latest version of their XMR app and updated the Ledger Firmware.

I had to do a complete reset of my Ledger Nano S (via the 24 word seed) as it got "wiped" during the installation of Ledger's latest XMR app.

After recovery, I made sure I successfully installed Ledger's latest Monero app. The Ledger again works flawlessly with v0.17.3.1 GUI & it's daemon "Oxygen Orion". So my node is up & running.

**Here is my problem**

When I try using v0.18.0.0, with the Ledger, I get the following ERROR message:

> Could't open wallet. Monero Ledger App doesn't support the current Monero version. Try to update the Monero Ledger App. At least 1.6.0 is required

Please help.

Comment: Same issue here running Windows 10 Pro, Monero GUI v0.18.0, Ledger Nano X with the Monero app v1.7.8 (latest). I also receive the error "Couldn't open wallet. Monero Ledger App doesn't support the current Monero version. Try to update the Monero Ledger App. At least 1.6.0 is required"

Comment: @Silarous - Please see my answer here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/13703/44

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

> Ledger Monero users, please be aware that version 1.8.0 of the Ledger Monero App is required in order to properly use CLI or GUI v0.18.0.0. Ledger Monero App 1.8.0 has yet to be released, so please do not upgrade yet.

As a temporary work around, you can downgrade to CLI/GUI v0.17.3.2. They can be directly downloaded (and verified) here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/uex4za/v01732_cli_gui_released_p2pool_ledger_nano_s_plus/

Lastly, the pull request to update the Ledger Monero App got merged recently. Additionally, a new tag was set. Thus, I expect the new version of the Ledger Monero App to be released soon. See:

https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-monero/tags

https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-monero/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed